# Can I use any color on default version of a website if I provide alternative color version that will be obiding by WCAG 2.1

Tags: accessibility

I am new to accessible content and wanted to get some POV from experts around here about that topic. If there is provided alternative version of color sets (black - white, black - yellow and enchanced default) can I use on default version colors that will not obide by WCAG 2.1.?

I would like to use CSS plugin to change clors via classes when clicked on button. I just wonder if that will be allowed then to use colors with not enough contrast.

Comment: It is technically allowed, but it would not be following the 'spirit' of WCAG. See for example https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2007/05/alternate-versions.html, that mentions as a reason for using alternate versions a situation where it is not possible to conform to provide full functionality - the reason "I like this color scheme better" is in a different category.

Comment: Note that this question is borderline off-topic on Stack Overflow, you could try [ux.se] instead which has a [wcag tag](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wcag).

Comment: First of all, thank you and I will move over to UX. Secondly, I am of the same opinion as you. It's hard for me to argue with a client who has had someone tell him that is technically allowed and therefore he may have a more appealing site. I heavily dislike going that route and honestly was borderline hoping for someone to point me to some proof that it is not allowed.

Comment: Instead of switching classes, you should switch the stylesheet. browsers already provide a menu to switch stylesheets if several are defined. Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547565/how-to-provide-an-accessible-high-contrast-alternative-to-a-pastel-color-scheme

Answer (score 1):

Best guidance is to have sufficient contrast by default. You mention black/white and black/yellow as alternatives. Those are considered "high contrast" and are not required by WCAG AA. In fact, not even WCAG AAA requires that, which only suggests a contrast of 7:1 ([WCAG 1.4.6](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#contrast-enhanced)).

Black/white has a contrast of 21:1 and black/yellow is 19.6:1. Those are extremely high contrasts. Having a contrast of 7:1 is still pretty high but is not required by standard WCAG 2.1 AA standards (but is a nice option to have - if you let the user choose their color scheme).

As an example, the "related questions" section on stackoverflow shows green buttons with white text.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The white text on a green background has a contrast of 2.4:1, which fails WCAG.

```
Foreground: #FFFFFF
Background: #5EBA7D
The contrast ratio is: 2.4:1
```

While stackoverflow.com *could* provide a link to an alternative site that has better contrast, why not just fix the "real" site?  Making the green a bit darker gives it a 4.6:1 contrast which makes it easier to read for *everyone*.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

```
Foreground: #FFFFFF
Background: #2A8649
The contrast ratio is: 4.6:1
```

Making the green even darker, #0B672A, gives it a 7:1 contrast which satisfies WCAG AAA without using "high contrast" mode.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

```
Foreground: #FFFFFF
Background: #0B672A
The contrast ratio is: 7.0:1
```

Comment: First of all, I am thankful for the answer. I get your point. I am of the perspective that it is better to do it properly on the default version of a website. I have a tough disagreement on that matter with a client though. If it is 'technically' allowed I may not have enough ground to stand on.

Comment: It IS technically allowed by the WCAG to offer an alternative version with sufficient contrast: [Providing a control with a sufficient contrast ratio that allows users to switch to a presentation that uses sufficient contrast](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/general/G174.html). Sorry for the bad news. Maybe this could be added to the answer?